# Calculate time difference for date format ('d/M/y H:i:s A')

Tags: php

I want to calculate time difference between current time and time stored in the db. `d/M/y H:i:s A` is the format where MS Sql stores the date and time.
The following code returns wrong value.

```
function time_difference($created_time)
{
    $str = $created_time;              // 03/Mar/17 12:35:00 PM
    $today = date('d/M/y H:i:s A');    // 06/Mar/17 06:35:15 AM
    $time_difference = $today - $str;  // Returns 3
}
```

is there anyway to convert `$str` and `$today` to seconds?

Comment: `$time_difference = strtotime($today - $str);`  it will give you difference in seconds

Comment: @Anant it returns boolean false

Comment: @Anant You probably mean `strtotime($today) - strtotime($str)`

Comment: @Mànìkàndàn str_replace function is the static way you are converting your date format please look up my update ans I'd use DateTime::createFromFormat() function for convert date fromate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like below:-

```
<?php
function time_difference($created_time)
{
        $str = $created_time;              // 03/Mar/17 12:35:00 PM
        $today = date('d/M/y H:i:s A');    // 06/Mar/17 06:35:15 AM
        return $time_difference = strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$today)) - strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$str));
}

echo  time_difference("03/Mar/17 12:35:00 PM");
```

Output:-https://eval.in/748622

Comment: @Mànìkàndàn  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 1):

```
function time_difference($created_time)
{
       $created = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/y H:i:s A', $created_time);
       return strtotime('now') - $created->getTimestamp(); 
}
```

Comment: This returns int 0

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function time_difference($created_time, $date ='',$new_date ='',$time_diff ='')
{

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/y H:i:s A', $created_time); 
    $new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $time_diff = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s')) - strtotime($new_date);
    return $time_diff;
}
echo time_difference('03/Mar/17 12:35:00 PM');
?>
```

[Working demo](https://eval.in/748668)